Angular SSR: CanActivate Guard Redirects to Error Page Before Loading Target Component
I have a simple routing guard in my Angular application that uses "@angular/ssr": "^18.0.5" which check for the "redirect" query param.
export const redirectGuard: CanActivateFn = (_, state): boolean | UrlTree => {
  const hasRedirect = state.root.queryParams['redirect'];
  const router = inject(Router);
  if(!hasRedirect) {
    return router.createUrlTree(['/error']);
  }

  return true;
};

The app.routes.ts:
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [redirectGuard],
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./features/login/login.component').then((m) => m.LoginComponent),
  },
  ...
    {
    path: 'error',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./features/error/error.component').then((m) => m.ErrorComponent),
  }
]

When I try to reach the application like: http://localhost:4000/?redirect=https:%2F%2FXXX.XXX-XXX.XXX.XXX%2F the page behave like this:

The error page is shown for a while and then the guard process and show the LoginComponent.

It happens since when in the server, it redirects to error page, then the guard runs on the browser, so it goes to login again. To solve this, perform the redirect only on the browser.
import { inject, Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

export const redirectGuard: CanActivateFn = (_, state): boolean | UrlTree => {
  const platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
  const hasRedirect = state.root.queryParams['redirect'];
  const router = inject(Router);
  if(!hasRedirect && isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
    return router.createUrlTree(['/error']);
  }

  return true;
};


This resolve the issue of error page being shown, but instead if i navigate to empty base path without redirect param, I see the LoginComponent for a while and then the ErrorComponent

@NiceToMytyuk if you have any redirect somewhere else you have to use this same approach of making it happen only on the server

I have no other redirects, the redirectGuard do the redirect to error page as "redirect" query is missing, but before it the LoginComponent is shown for a while.

@NiceToMytyuk you need to wrap your login html inside a defer block so that it's not rendered on the server this will solve your issue

I've tried to wrap it in defer like this but there is still the same issue

Okay that was an issue with the @defer where the getRedirect was undefined, seems working...
